# link dynamically two dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, json

```
//This is the html page


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
        <select id="officeType">
          <option value="">OfficeList</option>
          <option value="ministryDiv">Ministry</option>
          <option value="divisionBatayon">Division</option>
       </select>

       <select id="ministryList"></select>
    </div>   
   <script>
      var $select = $('#ministryList');
      $.getJSON('all-ministry-list.JSON',function(value){
          $select.html('');

          for(var i=0;i<value['data'].length;i++){
             $select.append('<option id="' +value['data'][i]['id'] +'">' +value['data'][i]['sitename_bn'] +'</option>');
          }
      });
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

//this is the all-ministry-list.JSON file

```
{
    "data": [

        {
            "id": "6484",
            "subdomain": "mohpw.portal.gov.bd",
            "sitename_en": "Ministry of Housing and Public Works",
            "sitename_bn": "গৃহায়ণ ও গণপূর্ত মন্ত্রণালয়",
            "weight": "99999"
        },
        {
            "id": "6487",
            "subdomain": "minland.portal.gov.bd",
            "sitename_en": "Ministry Of Land",
            "sitename_bn": "ভূমি মন্ত্রণালয়",
            "weight": "99999"
        }

    ]
}
//this is the ministry-child-list.JSON file
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "6209",
            "subdomain": "beza.portal.gov.bd",
            "sitename_en": "Bangladesh Economic Zones Authority",
            "sitename_bn": "বাংলাদেশ অর্থনৈতিক অঞ্চল কর্তৃপক্ষ",
            "weight": "99999"
        },
        {
            "id": "6218",
            "subdomain": "ngoab.portal.gov.bd",
            "sitename_en": "NGO Affairs Bureau",
            "sitename_bn": "এনজিও বিষয়ক ব্যুরো",
            "weight": "99999"
        },
        {
            "id": "6558",
            "subdomain": "bida.portal.gov.bd",
            "sitename_en": "Bangladesh Investment Development Authority (BIDA)",
            "sitename_bn": "বাংলাদেশ বিনিয়োগ উন্নয়ন কর্তৃপক্ষ",
            "weight": "99999"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here i have two dropdown menu.In first dropdown i give the value of option manually.In second dropdown i get the option value from json file.Now i want to connect together these two dropdown.For example when i click on Ministry i want to see the value of json file all-ministry-list.json in second dropdown ministryList and when i click on Division i want to see the value of json file ministry-child-list.json in second dropdown ministryList.How can i connect these two table?plz help

Comment: Not sure what your question is. You are saying, you are getting options for second dropdown from json file. And now you want to connect the dropdown on first dropdown value select? What about 2nd Division?

Comment: **when i click on Ministry i want to see the value of json file all-ministry-list.json in second dropdown ministryList** your are already seeing values in the second dropdown.?

Comment: how can we identify which value will show in second dropdown

Comment: i edit the file.Hope you can understand now.